# How can I connect my ionic app to two different API URLS in the same page? how to pass the id from the first url's data to the second url?

Tags: angular, laravel, api, ionic-framework

I'm building an ionic recipe app, the home page is calling a list of recipes names, ids and images using an API url which is www.forexample/recipeslist.com. 
The thing that I want is, I need to write smth which works as the following: 
When I press on any recipe name from that same page, I want it to direct the user to a page that contains that recipes details such as the ingredients, methods, etc .. 
These details will be called from a url named www.forexample.com/recipedetails/{id}
So i want it to take the clicked recipe's ID and add it to that url. 
How can I do it? How can I pass the ID from the first url's data to the second URL? Please help:(

Here's my .service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

const apiUrl = "https://forexample.com/recipeslist";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiLandingRecipesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body || [] ; }

  getDataUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(apiUrl, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }


}
```

Here's my homepage.ts file:

```
import { ApiLandingRecipesService} from '../api-landing-recipes.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-page',
  templateUrl: './landing-page.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing-page.page.scss'],
})
export class LandingPagePage implements OnInit {
  datauser: any[];
  constructor( public api: ApiLandingRecipesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDataUser();
  }
  async getDataUser() {
    await this.api.getDataUser()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.datauser =res;
        console.log(this.datauser);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Here's my homepage.html file:

```
<ion-card-header *ngFor="let data of datauser"> 
<p> {{data.recipename}} </p> 
</ion-card-header>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First change your api url to :

```
const apiUrl = "https://forexample.com/";
```

Second change this:

```
getDataUser(uri): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(apiUrl + uri, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Third change this in the main recipies page:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getDataUser();
  }

async getDataUser() {
    await this.api.getDataUser('recipeslist')
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.datauser =res;
        console.log(this.datauser);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Now in html of recepies change to:

```
<ion-card-header *ngFor="let data of datauser" routerLink="/detailspage/{{data.recipeid}}"> 
<p> {{data.recipename}} </p> 
</ion-card-header>
```

Now in app-routing.module.ts add this:

```
{ path: 'details/:id', loadChildren: ...' }
```

Now in details page :

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'; 
recordId = null;
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.recordId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.getDataUser(this.recordId);
  }

async getDataUser(recordId) {
    await this.api.getDataUser('recipeslist/' + recordId)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.datauser =res;
        console.log(this.datauser);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

I put different names of pages since i didn't understand your class naming for which is main page (home or receipies or landing) but the way i wrote coupd be clearer for you.

Comment: Thank you Mostafa so much, in the details html page I wrote   <ion-col *ngFor="let data of datauser">
        <ion-label>
         <p>{{reem.title}}</p> 
        </ion-label>
    </ion-col> 
but an error occurs which is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataUser' of undefined. Did u get what I want to show in the details page? I want to get data from the api url www.forexample.com/recipedetails/{id}

Comment: Yes i know that, inside this.api.getDataUser('recipedetails/ + recordId) , but since its a typescript error, then its not related to function itself in the page. Maybe check the api service implentation since the typescript error point that it can't be found.

Comment: Can you please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62114855/how-to-split-json-strings-to-arrays-in-ionic?noredirect=1#comment109859184_62114855 ?